# Is there a way to set static IP from API 30?

Tags: java, android

I'm developing a Android app (to run on API level 33 devices) and I need to set some wifi configurations programmatically.

I'm using WifiNetworkSuggestion with EnterpriseConfig, but there is no option to set static IP from this Classes.
I appreciate any help from community. Thanks in advance.

I'm already able to connect with a SSID, but the connection use DHCP setting.

My Code:

```
WifiEnterpriseConfig enterpriseConfig = new WifiEnterpriseConfig();
InputStream inStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.cert);

CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
X509Certificate certificate =(X509Certificate)cf.generateCertificate(inStream);
enterpriseConfig.setCaCertificate(certificate);
enterpriseConfig.setIdentity(userID);
enterpriseConfig.setPassword(userPass);
enterpriseConfig.setEapMethod(WifiEnterpriseConfig.Eap.PEAP);
enterpriseConfig.setAltSubjectMatch("my_domain");


List<WifiNetworkSuggestion> suggestionsList = new ArrayList<>();
WifiNetworkSuggestion suggestion = new WifiNetworkSuggestion.Builder()
    .setSsid(networkSSID)
    .setIsHiddenSsid(true)
    .setIsAppInteractionRequired(true)
    .setWpa2EnterpriseConfig(enterpriseConfig)
    .build();
suggestionsList.add(suggestion);

wifiManager.addNetworkSuggestions(suggestionsList);
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.